# Assigning a value/number/integer to an image

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I improve my code here, that has an array of image to have/assign a specific integer,value or number. that whenever it is displayed I can draw a circle on it programmatically. Could anyone suggest a way?

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{    
    if (self) {

        self.images = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"111.jpg",
                       @"112.jpg",
                       @"113.jpg",
                       @"114.jpg",
                       @"115.jpg",
                       @"116.jpg",
                       @"117.jpg",
                       @"118.png",
                       @"119.jpg",
                       @"120.jpg",
                       nil];

    }
}
```

Comment: You can add view and label on imageView and pass the number or anything to that label.

Comment: Or maybe you can tag the imageView with the number you want.

Comment: Is there any limit to assigning tags to images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array of NSDictionaries (instead of strings) and each dictionary can contain a key for the image name plus whatever other keys you want to add. Or even better, create an array of your own custom object (subclass NSObject) and then you can access the properties of each entry in the array without having to do a dictionary lookup.

Here is some sample code for the NSDictionary method:

```
- (id)init
{
    ...
    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ...
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    ...
    [images release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)addImagesToArrayWithImageName:(NSString *)imageName andTag:(int)tag
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    [dict setObject:imageName forKey:@"imageName"];
    [dict setObject:[NSNUmber numberWithInt:tag] forKey:@"tag"];
    [images addObject:dict];
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self addImagesToArrayWithImageName:@"111.jpg" andTag:0];
    [self addImagesToArrayWithImageName:@"112.jpg" andTag:1];
    ...
}
```

Comment: my goal is when a specific image is displayed a circle will be drawn.

Comment: To "draw" the circle, use a second UIImageView with a circle image that is transparent outside the circle. Add that as a subview to your main image and position it accordingly using setFrame.

Comment: can you give me some sample about the NSDictionaries you specify. thanks

Comment: I've tried your code but it doesn't display any image from the awakeFromNib. Having and error in the debugger: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithCapacity:]: capacity (4294967295) is ridiculous'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13c0052 0x1551d0a 0x12e81b7 0x131b97b 0x7f26 0xf590 0x18db5 0xbb6ec6 0x1394966 0x1394407 0x12f77c0 0x12f6db4 0x12f6ccb 0x1e5f879 0x1e5f93e 0x288a9b 0x208d 0x1ff5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)

Comment: I gave you the sample code to create your data structure that you use later when you display the images, not code to display images. Also, the error you are seeing is from your code not mine. I did not use initWithCapacity or dictionaryWithCapacity which is causing your error. Also, did you declare images as an NSMutableArray ivar in your controller?

Comment: Yes i declare it as ivar. Im declaring my images in my awakeFromNib too, so where am I going to put the `[self addImagesToArrayWithImageName:@"111.jpg" andTag:0];` part.

Comment: That part replaces your "self.images = [NSMutableArray ..." That part is what declares your images.

Comment: The "tag" is the specific integer you want to assign to that image. Which is what you said you wanted in your original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11036/discussion-between-joel-and-user1311817)

Comment: `- (void)init
{
    images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}` this part is causing an error too. It says Method was declared as an init method, but its implementation doesn't match because its result type is not an object pointer.